# Node.js Express: BodyParser Syntax

Tags: node.js, express

Hi everyone i am new to node.js and express. i am just experimenting with various node.js code from various tutorials.

As per the  official npm website correct syntax to use methodOverride is

```
// Be sure to place after the body parser if you want to accept the method 
// override using a post parameter
app.use(express.bodyParser());

// Accepts a single argument, the name of the method override parameter,
// defaults to "_method"
app.use(require('express-method-override')('method_override_param_name'));
```

But when i used this, i got the following error

```
Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and
ust be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#m
ddleware.
at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\exp
ess\lib\express.js:89:13)
```

As far as i researched app.use(express.bodyParser()) is  deprecated. Express no longer includes the bodyParser middleware. So to my guess app.use(bodyParser()) is right and i altered my code like this

```
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(require('express-method-override')('method_override_param_name'));
```

Below is my put functionality code

```
app.put('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  console.log('Sha Put testing');
  console.log(req.body);
  //user.findByIdAndUpdate({email: req.params.id},

  user.update({email: req.params.id},
    {
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        age   : req.body.age
    },  
    function(err, docs){
      if(err) res.json('Error here paiyaa  -->' + err);
      else
      { 
        console.log(docs);
        res.redirect('/user/'+req.body.email);
      }
  });

});
```

When i replace app.put with app.post it works fine. But my task is to achieve PUT functionality.As mentioned in express-method-override source, I have used hidden field with the name _method, which helps to override POST method, and facilitates PUT method.
My Edit form code is

```
<h1>Editing #{user.name}'s profile!</h1>
form(method="POST", action="/user/#{user._id}")
 input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="PUT")
 p Name:
  input(type="text", name="name", value="#{user.name}")
 p Age:
  input(type="number", name="age", value="#{user.age}")
 p
  input(type="submit")
```

When i run the above code it throws below error while submitting the form

```
Cannot POST /user/test@gmail.com
```

Can some expert help me to fix this and understand bit clear please

Answer (score 0):

You have a `PUT` route defined with `app.put`, but are trying to `POST` to it. The verbs need to match up, so either your request should be a `PUT` (makes sense for your `user.update` method) or change the route to `app.post`.

*EDIT*:
Looking at the source for `express-method-override`, your request body needs to have a `_method: 'PUT'` (as a default -- currently you are passing `'method_override_param_name'` property on it in order for the middleware to override the `POST` verb.

If you are not already, you should also be including the body-parser middleware. `npm install body-parser` on the commandline or add it to your `package.json` and run `npm install`. `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');` will then give the rest of your code what it needs to include the middleware.

Comment: Yes app.post works fine for me. But my task is to acheive PUT functionality.As far as i researched app.use(express.bodyParser()) is  deprecated. Express no longer includes the bodyParser middleware. So to my guess app.use(bodyParser()) is right. I don't know where i went wrong. Any suggestions to acheive PUT functionality?